# Save data in two tables in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a simple form in Cake :

[image]

I want to save the informations in the users and companies tables .

Users Table :

[image]

Companies table :

[image]

I'm in need to get two sql queries .

First of all : 
- Insert the new users with a new company id which will be created in companies table .

For instance with this case, testza,

users : (new entry)
testza password company id (new if of the new company entry)

companies (new entry) :
Id (3) Creaz (name) 500 000 (revenue_generated) .

I guess i'm clear :

companies/signup (view)

```
<div class="page-header">

    <h1>Company Registration</h1>

</div>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Company'); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username',array('label'=>'Login')); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password',array('label'=>'Password')); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.passwordconfirm',array('label'=>'Confirm password','type'=>'password')); ?>

        <hr>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.company_id', 
        array(
            'label'=>'Company',
            'options' => $companies,
            'empty' => 'Select Company Name'
        ));
        ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.revenue_generated',array('label'=>'Revenue Generated')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end('Envoyer'); ?>
```

the action signup of the Controller CompaniesController

```
<?php

class CompaniesController extends AppController{

    public $uses = array('User');

    public function signup() {

        $this->loadModel('Company');

        $companies = $this->Company->find('list'); //we get the authors from the database

        $this->set('companies', $companies);

        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put') ){

            $d = $this->request->data['User'];
            $c = $this->request->data['Company'];

            if($d['password'] != $d['passwordconfirm']){

                $this->Session->setFlash("Les mots de passes ne correspondent pas","notif",array('type'=>'error'));

            }

            else{

                if(empty($d['password']))

                    unset($d['password']);

                if($this->User->save($d) || $this->Company->save($c)){

                    $this->Session->setFlash("L'utilisateur a bien été enregistré","notif");

                }

            }

        }
    }
..............
```

User Model :

```
<?php 

class User extends AppModel{

    public $actsAs = array('Containable'); 

     public $belongsTo = array(        
        'Town' => array(
            'className' => 'Town'
        ),
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company'
        )
    ); 

    public $recursive = -1; 

    public $order = 'User.id DESC';

    public $validate = array(

        'username' => array(

            'rule'       => 'isUnique',

            'allowEmpty' => false,

            'message'    => "Ce nom d'utilisateur est déja pris"

        ),

        'password' => array(

            'rule'       => 'notEmpty',

            'message'    => "Vous ne pouvez pas entrer de mot de pase"

        )

    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()){

        if(!empty($this->data['User']['password'])){

            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);

        }

        return true; 

    }

}
```

Company Model :

```
<?php 

class Company extends AppModel{

    public $validate = array(
        'revenue_generated' => array(
            'rule' =>'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Enter Your Generated Revenue.',
            'required' => true
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: you're using ($this->User->save($d) || $this->Company->save($c)) i guess it doesn't work, you need to get the company_id to inser it user ... is that the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes i need the company_id in the users table with a new entry of user and a second insert into with the new entry of the company . For the moment when i click on the submit button i have only the entry of user without company_id and no entry for companies .

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going to use an existing company already in the database from the drop down menu, try saving both models at the same time with `Model::saveAssociated()`. This will save both records at once for you, and insert the Company `id`, automatically into the foreign key for the users table: `User.company_id` on successful save.

Replace your two `save()` function calls with one call to `saveAssociated()`:

```
if($this->User->saveAssociated($data)) {
    //do something after save.
}
```

Here is a complete example using your existing code:

```
$this->set('companies', $this->Company->find('list'));

if($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

    //Dont need to seperate this anymore
    //$d = $this->request->data['User'];
    //$c = $this->request->data['Company'];

    if($this->request->data['User']['password'] != $this->request->data['User']['passwordconfirm']){
        $this->Session->setFlash("Les mots de passes ne correspondent pas","notif",array('type'=>'error'));
    } else {

        if(empty($this->request->data['User']['password']))
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);

        if($this->User->saveAssociated($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash("L'utilisateur a bien été enregistré","notif");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Company` model is also missing the `hasMany` relationship for User. Add this to `Company` model:

```
public $hasMany = array('User');
```

Refer to Cake Manual here for documentation on `SaveAssociated()`:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but where do i have to put if($this->User->saveAssociated($data)) { ?

Comment: i try your second code, i added the has many relationship for User and i get two errors : Warning: Illegal string offset 'line' in /home/lukrixco/public_html/hasb/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php on line 653

Warning (2): strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php, line 436]

Comment: @user3790914 I updated the example with where to use the function. See above. It should replace where the `save()` function was.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution i suggest and i work with, start by saving the company first to generat the id the save the user :

```
if($this->Company->save($this->request->data['Company'])){
$this->Company->User->save($this->request->data['User']); // if save doesn't work try $this->Company->User->saveAll($this->request->data['User']);
...
}
```

**update :**
add the hasmany relation in the company model :

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

hope ut helps.

Comment: Ok thanks but it didn't fix it . With $this->Company->User->save($this->request->data['User']); or saveAll now i'm not getting the call to member error but i still have a query only for users , so not affecetd the companies table and for users i don't have the id of the company, because the entry for companies doesn't exist .

Comment: look here : http://www.lukrix.com/hasb/companies/signup you could see the queries .

Comment: still the same :/ i did the same for the UsersController

Comment: first of all , you retrieve the data of the company table to fill the list, so you don't need to resave the company , you'll save just the user and you'll have the company_id in the user just by editing the view : Company.company_id to User.company_id and move the view to the User and not in Company controller.

Comment: I understand, but i need in this form to create in the same form a company that is linked to the user (which is created also after the submit button) so i don't know how can i do it =D

Comment: look now when i want to be loged, http://www.lukrix.com/hasb/users/login login (creaz) password(creaz), error of query because he searched information of generated_revenue

Comment: if you want to save the company too , you have to add the field of the company in the view or add it in the controller before save it...but what you're doing in wrong conceptually...what do you want to do in all ??

Comment: this is what i did, i changed my form, when i click on the submit button now, i have two insert into, a new entry is created for companies and the users too . I just need now the company_id save for the user and i don't know why but the revenue_generated is not save for the compny (only name and id) . we're close to the answer .

Comment: for the revenue_generated , in the view rename the field  Company.reveune_generated leave it just revenue_generated..

Comment: did u try the other answer ? what type of revenue_generated in DB mysql ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60549/discussion-on-answer-by-may-saghira-save-data-in-two-tables-in-cakephp).